# Fetching content binary from database or fetching content by its link from storage service

Tags: sql, database, amazon-s3, google-cloud-storage

For an app (web + phone) there are two options:

1. Image binaries in database. Server replies to app HTTP request with images as base64
2. Images in storage service like *Amazon S3* or *Azure Blob Storage* or a [self-hosted](https://github.com/minio/minio) one. Image links in database. Server handles app HTTP requests by sending back only the links to images. The app fetches the images from storage by their link

[image: 2 options]

Which option above is the standard practice? Which one has less trouble down the road?

Answer (score 1):

To some extent, the answer to this question is always opinion based, and partly depends on the specific use case.

I would think that the second approach is used more often. One reason is that normally, storage within a database is slightly more expensive than file storage in many cases. Also, what is the real use case? Assuming you use HTML pages that reference images via the `img` element or via CSS as background image, then the base64 return value would not be that useful, and OTOH the more complicated graphic at the bottom of your picture would get a bit more simple from the client view: The resolution of the link would be resolved by the server when generating the HTML and determine the `src` of the `img`, and then the browser would simply apply standard HTML logic and request the image data from the storage service via HTTP.

However, if you would want to optimize load times (and your images would be more or less unique per page so that browser caching of images across pages would not help much), then you could use data URLs embedded into the HTML, and then the first approach could potentially be useful. In this case, all the logic including the generation of the data URL within the HTML would be handled on the server, and the browser would have a single http  request.